# PHP Script Error to Return Data from a Database

Tags: php

I have this PHP Script to return data from a database. I send a JSON string (`[{"user_id":"2"}]`) to the PHP script. I decode this JSON object, and use it within a SELECT SQL query as shown below to then encode the results in a JSON object. This PHP returns a error 500 when I call it though so I wondered whether anyone can see my problem within this script.

```
<?php
    require 'connect-mysql.php';

    $json = $_POST['json']; 

    $array = json_decode($json);

    $id = $array[0]->user_id;

    $mysql_qry = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM exercise_result INNER JOIN 
    split ON exercise_result.split_id = split.split_id WHERE user_id = $id";

    $result = mysqli_query($dbcon ,$mysql_qry);
    $rows = array();    

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($rows);
?>
```

If anyone can spot my problem, this would be appreciated!

**UPDATE**

Due to using university servers I have limited access on server logs.

I altered the `PHP` to instead of decode a `JSON` object. I just `POST` the `ID`. Below is my updated code, still unsure of the problem of the original code but I have found a working solution.

```
<?php
    require 'connect-mysql.php';

    $id = $_POST['id']; 

    $mysql_qry = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM exercise_result INNER JOIN split ON exercise_result.split_id = split.split_id WHERE user_id = $id";

    $result = mysqli_query($dbcon ,$mysql_qry);
    $rows = array();    

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($rows);
?>
```

Comment: Always when developing and testing code, turn error reporting to its maximum `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and (maybe not convenient with a json API but still useful) display errors: `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` both at the top of your code. Meanwhile, watch your web server's error log for details on the 500.

Comment: A 500 error means you can find out what the *actual* error is in your server's error log, or by enabling error reporting. Without an error message, all we can do is guess. My guess is you're getting a SQL syntax error on `DISTINCT *`, which means `$result` is `false`, which means you're then getting a fatal error on `mysqli_fetch_array()` because it's expecting `$result` to be something other than a boolean. But that's pure speculation.

Comment: Nothing jumps out at me in this code, but it could be due to `$dbcon` not having connected correctly. Be sure to sanitize `$id` as well - ideally you would be using `mysqli_prepare()` to prepare and execute this with a param, but for the integer value at a minimum you should call `intval($id)`